# Java: Access a file in a embedded jar file

Tags: java

I have a jar file called "jar1.jar". Inside, it has another jar file called "jar2.jar".

The content of "jar2.jar" is: "file.txt".

```
jar1.jar
|
|-> jar2.jar
    |
    |-> file.txt
```

I would like to get the content of "file.txt".

My codes are below:

```
try{
    String secondJarPath=Myclass.class.getResource("jar2.jar").getPath();

    //An exception is thrown
    JarFile secondJar = new JarFile(secondJarPath);

    JarEntry entry =secondJar.getJarEntry("file.txt");
    InputStream inputStream = entry.getInputStream(entry);
    String content= IOUtils.toString(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

}
catch(IOException e){
}
```

However, an exception is thrown in the line "JarFile secondJar = new JarFile(secondJarPath);", saying "The filename, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect"

Can anyone help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Isn't extracting `jar2` from `jar1` an option?

Answer (score 1):

```
try{
   String firstJarPath = Junk.class.getResource("jar1.jar").getPath();
    JarFile firstJar = new JarFile(firstJarPath);
    JarEntry entry = firstJar.getJarEntry("jar2.jar");

    InputStream isJar2 = firstJar.getInputStream(entry);
    JarInputStream jisJar2 = new JarInputStream(isJar2);
    JarEntry textFileEntry = jisJar2.getNextJarEntry();

    if (textFileEntry.isDirectory()) {
        jisJar2.close();
        firstJar.close();
        throw new Exception("didn't expect a directory");
    } else {
        int size = (int) textFileEntry.getSize();
        if (size <= 0) {
            System.out.print("ignore entry " + textFileEntry.getName() + " as size=" + size);
        } else {
            byte[] fileBytes = new byte[size];
            IOUtils.read(jisJar2, fileBytes, 0, size);
            ByteArrayInputStream ibs = new ByteArrayInputStream(fileBytes);
            // ibs should be your file, so now do something with it....
        }
    }
    jisJar2.close();
    firstJar.close();

}

catch(IOException e){
}
```